# Prove or Disprove $\sum_{x=-(n+2c)}^n x+c = 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was playing around with series at an internet cafe and I stumbled upon this "identity":
$$\sum_{x=-(n+2c)}^n x+c = 0$$

I've tried multiple times with a random number generator and the only times that the identity is not true is when the series isn't viable.

I haven't seen anything like this before and on the internet but its hard searching using summations on google. I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this before or whether its something "new", and any possible explanation for why it's correct.

Comment: Ok, so Prove or Disprove would work better next time I come across something like this?

Comment: Actually, it is very easy to show. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{x=-(n+2c)}^n(x+c)&=\sum_{x=0}^{2n+2c}(x-n-2c+c) &&\textsf{shift index variable}\\\\
&=\sum_{x=0}^{2n+2c}(x-n-c)&&\textsf{simplify}\\\\
&=\left(\sum_{x=0}^{2n+2c}x\right)-\left(\sum_{x=0}^{2n+2c}(n+c)\right)&&\textsf{separate constant terms}\\\\
&=\frac{(2n+2c)(2n+2c+1)}{2}-(2n+2c+1)(n+c)&&\textsf{apply well-known formulas}\\\\
&=0&&\textsf{simplify}
\end{align*}$$
The well-known formulas in particular would be
$$\sum_{x=0}^{r}x=\frac{r(r+1)}{2}\qquad \sum_{x=0}^rc=(r+1)c$$

Comment: Actually, if you use the sum of arithmetic sequence, it is very easy to show. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Noting that $\{x+c\}_{x=-(n+2c)}^{n}$ is an arithmetic sequence, namely
$$ -(n+2c)+c,-(n-1+2c),\cdots,n+c $$
 with $a_1=-(n+2c)+c=-n-c$, the difference of successive members $d=1$ and the last term $a_m=n+c$.
So
$$ \sum_{x=-(n+2c)}^n(x+c)=\sum_{k=1}^ma_k=\frac m2(a_1+a_m)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

To show
$\sum_{x=-(n+2c)}^n (x+c) = 0$:

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{x=-(n+2c)}^n (x+c) 
&=\sum_{x=-(n+c)}^{n+c} \\ 
&=0\\
\end{array}
$

since for each positive term
there is a matching negative term
and vice-versa.